# INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: <TableName>is not mapped [FROM <TableName>]

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, exception

I am currently learning hibernate, unable to fetch data from oracle.. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Please find the below configuration files, pojo class and main method...

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        </property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:oracle:thin:***
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            ***
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            ***
        </property>

        <mapping resource="tutorialspoint/example/Pojo_S.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Pojo Class**

```
package tutorialspoint.example;

public class Pojo_S {

    int SId;
    String SCode;
    String SName; 

    public int getSId() {
        return SId;
    }
    public void setSId(int SId) {
        SId = SId;
    }
    public String getSCode() {
        return SCode;
    }
    public void setSCode(String SCode) {
        SCode = SCode;
    }
    public String getSName() {
        return SName;
    }
    public void setSName(String SName) {
        SName = SName;
    }

}
```

**Pojo_S.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="tutorialspoint.example.Pojo_S" table="S">

        <id name="SId" type="int" column="S_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="SCode" column="S_CODE" type="string" />
        <property name="SName" column="S_NAME" type="string" />

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Main Method**

```
package tutorialspoint.example;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class MainApp {

    private static SessionFactory factory; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            System.out.println("In Main method of MainApp...");

            Configuration configure=new Configuration();  
            configure.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            factory = configure.buildSessionFactory();

            MainApp mainApp = new MainApp();
            mainApp.listDetails_S();
        }
        catch(Throwable ex){

            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 

        }
    }

    public void listDetails_S(){
        System.out.println("In listDetails_S method of MainApp...");

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try{

            List details = session.createQuery("FROM S").list(); 
            for (Iterator iterator = details.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
                Pojo_S detail = (Pojo_S) iterator.next(); 
                System.out.print("\nSId: " + detail.getSId());
                System.out.print("\nSCode: " + detail.getSCode());
                System.out.print("\nSName: " + detail.getSName());
            }
            tx.commit();
        }


        catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }finally {
            session.close(); 
        }
```

**Error Logs**

```
In Main method of MainApp...
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.2 cr4
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: Reading mappings from resource: tutorialspoint/example/Pojo_S.hbm.xml
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
INFO: Mapping class: tutorialspoint.example.Pojo_S -> S
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: Configured SessionFactory: null
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:12 PM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:12 PM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:12 PM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: autocommit mode: false
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:12 PM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: using driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver at URL: jdbc:oracle:****
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:12 PM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: connection properties: {user=***, password=****}
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: RDBMS: Oracle, version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC driver: Oracle JDBC driver, version: 11.2.0.2.0
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory buildTransactionFactory
INFO: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory getTransactionManagerLookup
INFO: No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC batch size: 15
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Scrollable result sets: enabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Connection release mode: auto
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Default batch fetch size: 1
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Generate SQL with comments: disabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query language substitutions: {}
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Second-level cache: enabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query cache: disabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createCacheProvider
INFO: Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Statistics: disabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Default entity-mode: pojo
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl <init>
INFO: building session factory
In listDetails_S method of MainApp...
Mar 10, 2016 12:06:41 PM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory addInstance
INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: S is not mapped [FROM S]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3056)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2945)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:688)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:544)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
    at tutorialspoint.example.MainApp.listDetails_S(MainApp.java:42)
    at tutorialspoint.example.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:24)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is, obviously, here

```
List details = session.createQuery("FROM S").list();
```

In HQL you need to use persistent class names, not table names.

```
List details = session.createQuery("FROM Pojo_S").list();
```

And you can use more simply code

```
List<Pojo_S> details = session.createQuery("FROM Pojo_S").list(); 
for (Pojo_S detail : details){
    System.out.print("\nSId: " + detail.getSId());
    System.out.print("\nSCode: " + detail.getSCode());
    System.out.print("\nSName: " + detail.getSName());
}
```